# Trying to image SD card with wheesy-raspbian - dd command fails with "No such file or directory"

Tags: sd-card, raspbian-wheezy

I'm new to RPi.  I'm trying to follow the instructions found at: 
http://xmodulo.com/2013/11/write-raspberry-pi-image-sd-card.html

I've downloaded the zip, extracted it into a temp directory, and now I'm trying to run the dd command like so:

```
jj@devbox:/$ sudo dd bs=4M if=/tmp/wheesy/2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img=/dev/sdb
dd: opening `/tmp/wheesy/2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img=/dev/sdb': No such file or directory
```

**What I've done so far:**

1. I've tried running "gksudo gparted" to confirm the name of the sd card. From the drop down list, I see that the SD card is called "/dev/sdb".  When I select the SD card from the drop down to get details on it, under the Partitions section, I see two lines:

   line 1 - unallocated partition, unallocated file system, size 4MiB

   line 2 - /dev/sdb1, fat32 file system, 3.39GiB

I've tried the dd command using both /dev/sdb and /dev/sdb1.

1. I've made sure that the SD card is unmounted before I run the dd command.  I launch nautilus and right click on the drive... and I ensure that "Mount" is an option.  I'm assuming if it is, it means that it's currently unmounted.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing the `of=`

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/tmp/wheesy/2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: doh!  I just tried it and yes, it seems to be getting a little further.  Thanks.  I'll accept your answer as soon as the site lets me

Comment: We've all been there. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/tmp/wheesy/2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img=/dev/sdb
```

That should be:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/tmp/wheesy/2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb
```

The site you linked does have it correctly:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/image of=/dev/sdc
```

It's important to pay attention and at least have a look at manual pages (`man dd`) when you do this stuff so you have a bit of understanding of what's going on.

Comment: @goldilocks... I misinterpreted the "of".  I kept reading it as a part of the image name.  But thanks for the reminder to check the man pages.

Comment: Totally understandable ("image of", lol -- whoops), like Gerben says we've all been there.  What should tip you off in this case is the error message with the wrong filename.